# LDAP SearchResult does not contain user properties

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I'm using `DirectorySearcher.FindOne()` method.

I have specified `Mobile` number in my Active Directory user properties. My search filter looks like this

```
(&(ObjectClass=User)(mobile=+11111111111))
```

With this filter I'm able to get appropriate user.

I've also specified Fax number in my AD user properties, but `SearchResult` does not contain Fax property. In fact `SearchResult` contain only one property, but I'm expecting all of user properties returned, including fax number.

Should I modify my query to get fax number returned? Maybe changes to my AD user or LDAP server required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `DirectorySearcher`, you can define what properties will be included in `SearchResult` by using the **`PropertiesToLoad`** collection. If you don't specify anything, you only get the distinguished LDAP name

So try something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://-your-base-LDAP-path-here-");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);
searcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=User)(mobile=+11111111111))";

// DEFINE what properties you need !
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Mobile");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Fax");

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

if (result != null)
{
   if (result.Properties["Fax"] != null)
   {
      string fax = result.Properties["Fax"][0].ToString();
   }

   if (result.Properties["Mobile"] != null)
   {
      string mobile = result.Properties["Mobile"][0].ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Great thanks! Only have to put "facsimileTelephoneNumber" insted of "Fax". Is there any way to specify which properties (or all the properties) to return in filter?

Comment: @user1016945: no, the place to specify which properties to return is `PropertiesToLoad` - nothing else.

Comment: Don't you need to add `[0]`? `result.Properties["Fax"][0].ToString()`